# How to exit a function from another function?

Tags: python

I want to exit a function in another function if statement is True. I am using multiprocessing so they are running concurrently.

I want to make something like this:

```
def A():
    while True:
        if condition is True:
            #do something
        else:
            True

def B():
    while True:
        if condition is True:
            #stop A() function
        else:
            True

def main():
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=A())
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=B())
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What makes you think `A()` will be running simultaneously with `B()`?

Comment: Sorry, i don't quite understand. I use multiprocessing so they should run together...

Comment: Show us the threading code then

Comment: There, i edited the post.

Comment: You probably meant `target=A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple synchronization primitives you could use, such as a condition variable:

You could use a [mp.Condition()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Condition) calling

```py
while not predicate():
    cv.wait()
```

in `A()` and `notify()` in `B()`

Comment: I need the A() function to run while waiting. Is that possible?

Comment: You could have a 3rd process running which destroys the process where A is running in as soon as the condition is fulfilled

Comment: Can you provide an example?